# PHP Warning... should be compatible with

Tags: php

Ao realizar *deploy* dos meus arquivos, notei que algumas funções que estavam funcionando normalmente no localhost (servidor local) não se comportaram como esperado no servidor de hospedagem, mais especificamente, quando preciso utilizar as *Classes* que criei. O servidor gerou um arquivo de erro, *error_log*.

Arquivo *error_log*:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Classes que utilizo nesta operação,
*Produtos.php*:

```
<?php
require_once "Crud.php";
class Produtos extends Crud {
    private $tabela;

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->tabela = "produtos";
    }

    public function store($params, $values) {
        parent::store($this->tabela, $params, $values);
    }

    public function index($column, $restriction) {
        return parent::index($column, $this->tabela, $restriction);
    }

    public function show($column, $restriction) {
        return parent::show($column, $this->tabela, $restriction);
    }

    public function update($setters, $values) {
        parent::update($this->tabela, $setters, $values);
    }

    public function excluir($restriction, $values) {
        parent::excluir($this->tabela, $restriction, $values);
    }
}
?>
```

*Crud.php*:

```
<?php
require_once "Conexao.php";
class Crud extends Conexao {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        parent::conectar();
    }

    public function store($tabela, $params, $values) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO $tabela VALUES($params)";
        if (parent::executarSql($sql, $values)) {
            echo "<script>alert('Produto cadastrado com sucesso!');window.location.href='../../../addproduto.php'</script>";
        } else {
            echo "<script>alert('Falha ao cadastrar produto, contate o administrador!');window.location.href='../../../addproduto.php'</script>";
        }
    }
    public function index($column, $tabela, $restriction) {
        $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT $column FROM $tabela $restriction";
        return parent::executarFetchAll($sql, $restriction);
    }
    public function show($column, $tabela, $restriction) {
        $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT $column FROM $tabela $restriction";
        return parent::executarFetchAll($sql, $restriction);
    }
    public function update($tabela, $setters, $values) {
        $sql = "UPDATE $tabela SET $setters";
        if (parent::executarSql($sql, $values)) {
            echo "Update efetuado com sucesso!";
        } else {
            echo "Falha ao realizar update!";
        }

    }
    public function excluir($tabela, $restriction, $values) {
        $sql = "DELETE FROM $tabela $restriction";
        if (parent::executarSql($sql, $values)) {
            echo "Exclusão efetuada com sucesso!";
        } else {
            echo "Falha ao realizar exclusão!";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

*Conexao.php*:

```
<?php
class Conexao {
    private $usuario;
    private $senha;
    private $bd;
    private $servidor;
    private $conexao;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->usuario = "*****";
        $this->senha = "******";
        $this->bd = "*****";
        $this->servidor = "******";
    }

    public function conectar() {
        $this->conexao = new PDO(
            "mysql:host=$this->servidor;dbname=$this->bd",
            $this->usuario,
            $this->senha,
            array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8")
        );
    }

    public function executarSql($sql, $valores) {
        $comando = $this->conexao->prepare($sql);
        foreach ($valores as $indice => &$valor) {
            $comando->bindParam($indice, $valor);
        }
        return $comando->execute();
    }

    public function executarFetchAll($sql, $valores) {
        $comando = $this->conexao->prepare($sql);
        if ($valores != null) {
            foreach ($valores as $indice => &$valor) {
                $comando->bindParam($indice, $valor);
            }
        }
        $comando->execute();
        return $comando->fetchAll();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Antes de mais nada, poderia justificar porque a classe `Produtos` herda da classe `Crud`, que por sua vez herda da classe `Conexao`? Conhece o princípio de substituição de Liskov? Como você avaliaria esse princípio no seu código?

Comment: Eu poderia utilizar somente a classe `Crud` herdando de `Conexao`, mas resolvi criar a classe `Produtos`, pois futuramente irei adicionar mais algumas regras de negócio que só se aplicam a ela. Não conheço o princípio citado, irei pesquisar sobre.

Comment: O erro acontece basicamente porque você está utilizando herança onde não deveria utilizar, adicionando problemas que não deveriam existir. O princípio de Liskov irá explicar bem porque essa situação não se deveria utilizar herança, principalmente referente ao erro obtido. Neste caso faria mais sentido utilizar composição entre as classes.